# Parallel for loop over range of array indices in C++17

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, c++17

I need to update a 100M-element array and would like to do it in parallel.  `std::for_each(std::execution::par, ...)` seems great for this, except that the update needs to access elements of other arrays depending on the index that I am updating.  A minimal *serial* working example of the kind of thing I'm trying to parallelize might look like this:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 100'000'000; i++)
    d[i] = combine(d[i], s[2*i], s[2*i+1]);
```

I could of course manually spawn threads, but that is a lot more code than `std::for_each`, so it would be great to find an elegant way to do this with the standard library.  So far I have found some not very elegant ways of using `for_each`, for instance:

- Compute the index by using pointer arithmetic on the address of the array element.
- Implement my own bogus iterator in the spirit of boost's `counting_range`.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried? Why didn't it work? Please show a [mre]

Comment: "but that is a lot more code" isn't really an argument. Especially since that doesn't sound like additional 100k lines of code. More like 10.

Comment: @freakish It might not be a lot lines of code, but it would be code with a lot of knobs to tune, like how many threads to use, what stride, etc. Presumably `for_each` does all of this already.

Answer (score 4):

`std::ranges` should be able to help if you have access to c++20, you can iterate over the indexes rather than your data:

```
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> d(100);
    std::ranges::iota_view indexes((size_t)0, d.size());
    std::for_each(std::execution::par, indexes.begin(), indexes.end(), [&d](size_t i)
    {
        std::cout << i << "," << d[i] << "\n";
    });
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is here "in parallel"? You only wrote another way of for loop.... I can't see what that helps, maybe I have overseen it...

Comment: You asked how to get an index inside `std::for_each`, this shows you how, if hope adding the extra arguments to make it parallel is reasonably obvious

Comment: No, I am not the OP :-) I got your point, we can have execution policies in `for_each`. Thanks!

Comment: @greygore is correct. This doesn't work due to the error "Parallel algorithms require forward iterators or stronger.", at least on VS 2019 in C++20 mode. Is there a variant that actually works?

Comment: @AllTheRage works in the latest VS: https://godbolt.org/z/b5PEjTaz8

Comment: @Alan, Thanks. This is a very recent fix. It didn't work in 19.33 but does work in the new 19.34.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to iterate over the *indexes* rather than the *items*. I think C++20 `std::ranges` gives you an easy way to do this, or you can use one of the Boost `range` methods. I'm not sure why you would consider rolling your own in the *spirit* of Boost `counting_range` when you could just, well, *use* Boost :-)

Having said that, I've actually opted for that roll-your-own approach, simply to make the code self-contained with neither C++20 nor Boost:  feel free to replace `paxrange` with one of the other methods depending on your needs:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

// Seriously, just use Boost :-)

class paxrange {
    public:
        class iterator {
            friend class paxrange;
            public:
                long int operator *() const { return value; }
                const iterator &operator ++() { ++value; return *this; }
                iterator operator ++(int) { iterator copy(*this); ++value; return copy; }

                bool operator ==(const iterator &other) const { return value == other.value; }
                bool operator !=(const iterator &other) const { return value != other.value; }

            protected:
                iterator(long int start) : value (start) { }

            private:
                unsigned long value;
        };

        iterator begin() const { return beginVal; }
        iterator end() const { return endVal; }
        paxrange(long int  begin, long int end) : beginVal(begin), endVal(end) {}
    private:
        iterator beginVal;
        iterator endVal;
};
int main() {
    // Create a source and destination collection.

    std::vector<int> s;
    s.push_back(42); s.push_back(77); s.push_back(144);
    s.push_back(12); s.push_back(6);
    std::vector<int> d(5);

    // Shows how to use indexes with multiple collections sharing index.

    auto process = [s, &d](const int idx) { d[idx] = s[idx] + idx; };
    paxrange x(0, d.size());
    std::for_each(x.begin(), x.end(), process); // add parallelism later.

    // Debug output.

    for (const auto &item: s) std::cout << "< " << item << '\n';
    std::cout << "=====\n";
    for (const auto &item: d) std::cout << "> " << item << '\n';
}
```

The "meat" of the solution is the three lines in the middle of `main()`, where you set up a function for call-backs, one that takes the index rather than the item itself.

Inside that function, you use that index plus as many collections as needed, to set up the destination collection, very similar to what you desire.

In my case, I simply wanted the output vector to be the input vector but with the index added to each element, as per the output:

```
< 42
< 77
< 144
< 12
< 6
=====
> 42
> 78
> 146
> 15
> 10
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple [header-only library in Github](https://github.com/tirimatangi/Lazy) which might help you.

Your minimal example can be parallelized like this. However, presumably due to cache cooling, the runtime will not scale down linearly with the number of cores.

```
#include "Lazy.h"

double combine(double a, double b, double c)
{
    if (b > 0.5 && c < 0.4)
        return a + std::exp(b * c + 1);
    else if (b*c < 0.2)
        return a * 0.8 + (1-c) * (1-b);
    else
        return std::exp(1.0 / a) + b + c;
}

// Generate index split for parallel tasks
auto getIndexPairs(std::size_t N, std::size_t numSplits)
{
    std::vector<std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t>> vecPairs(numSplits);
    double dFrom = 0, dTo = 0;
    for (auto i = 0; i < numSplits; ++i) {
        dFrom = dTo;
        dTo += N / double(numSplits);
        vecPairs[i] = {std::size_t(dFrom), std::min(std::size_t(dTo), N)};
    }
    vecPairs[numSplits-1].second = N;
    return vecPairs;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    const std::size_t N = 100000000;
    const std::size_t C = std::thread::hardware_concurrency(); // Number of parallel finder threads
    std::vector<double> d(N);
    std::vector<double> s(2*N);

    // Fill d and s with some values
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        s[i] = double(i) / N;
        s[i + N] = double(i + N) / N;
        d[i] = N - i;
    }
     
    // Run combine(...) in parallel in C threads
    Lazy::runForAll(getIndexPairs(N, C), [&](auto pr) {
        for (int i=pr.first; i<pr.second; ++i)
            d[i] = combine(d[i], s[2*i], s[2*i+1]);
        return nullptr; // Dummy return value
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I asked ChatGPT4.0, she tell me a result. the performance of the method is similar to OpenMP

```
std::transform(std::execution::par, A,A+n,B,C,[](float x, float y){
    return x+y;
});
```

the result is C[i] = A[i]+B[i].

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJ57m.png)

Comment: This depends on the transform using the same indices into each argument.  But the question is using `i`, `2*i` and `2*i+1`.

Comment: ChatGPT responses are not appropriate as answers on Stack Exchange (and they are often wrong/misleading). See [AI Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy)

Answer (score -2):

@Alan Birtles answer does not work with a parallel execution policy, as it errors out to "static_assert failed: 'Parallel algorithms require forward iterators or stronger.'".

A potential alternative is to make an iterator vector, but it won't be as space-efficient.

```cpp
std::vector<std::size_t> indexes(d.size());
std::iota(indexes.begin(), indexes.end(), 0);

std::for_each(std::execution::par, indexes.begin(), indexes.end(), [&](size_t i) {
   std::cout << i << ',' << d[i] << '\n';
}
```